# Converting CGAffineTransform to NSString

Tags: iphone

i want to save transform applied to uiview offline so i could retain the changes for later usage.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**NSString** to **CGAffineTransform**

```
CGAffineTransformFromString(NSString *string);
```

**CGAffineTransform** to **NSString**

```
NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform transform)
```

**Example:**

```
CGAffineTransform transform=CGAffineTransformFromString(likeBelowNSString);

NSString *transformAsNSString=NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(transform);
```

Unfortunately, these are not available on OS X.

Comment: Never even knew they existed! Deleting my redundant answer.